# Google fit api - activities (manual, id 113 and others)

Tags: php, google-api, google-fit

So I'm fighting currently with Google Fit Rest Api in PHP (pure, not from GitHub since I find documentation a bit weak, at least for me) and I got some questions.

**1.** I run

```
{base_uri}/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.activity.segment:com.google.android.gms:session_activity_segment/datasets/{timestamp_period}
```

To get list of user activities and thought the result value is activity type ID till yesterday when it **poped me ID no. 113** from crossfit activity [(list stops at 112)](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/activity-types) 
Do You know why it happened? Or maybe my thinking is wrong and it's not activity type ID - then how can I get it? Weird tho since it's proper on other activities...

**2.** I need to identify manual activities from tracked activities, I thought I have found at least part-solution that this:

```
{base_uri}/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.distance.delta:com.google.android.gms:merge_distance_delta/datasets/{timestamp_period}
```

returns me value only if activity was manual, in other cases I need to run this:

```
{base_uri}/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.distance.delta:com.google.android.gms:from_high_accuracy_location<-derived:com.google.location.sample:com.google.android.gms:merge_high_fidelity/datasets/{timestamp_period}
```

to get tracked ones but it failes even to that and looks like my walking tracked yesterday was manual.
Do You know some solution how can I get if activity was added manually or using tracker?

**3.** Do You know how to get description of activity?

Comment: Can you add the response where you get the 113 ID no?

Comment: There You go: [link](http://i.imgur.com/F5bPFYb.png)